# How to I do a simple "OR" query?

Tags: php, sql, search

I want to do a query by adding a "OR" statement.  Using what i have below won't show all entries.  What am i doing wrong?

```
//$q = search variable;

$sql = "SELECT name, id_code from codes WHERE (id_code = '$q') OR (name='$q')";
```

Comment: Hat does the query look like if your print it out? Can you confirm the value of `$q` is to be found in `codes`?

Comment: Echo the value of `$sql` and see what that gives you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `SELECT name, id_code from codes WHERE id_code = '$q' OR name='$q'` (i.e. without the parentheses)?

Comment: It should work with the parenthesis, even though they are not required.

Comment: Thanks! Just did some testing if it would and came up with the same conclusion. This is why I love SO.  I learn more by answering than asking.

Comment: Ok, i think the issue is that i need to use LIKE instead of = so all i have to do is substitute, no?

Comment: @ariel, LIKE does something very different. What exactly are you trying to query? Also, did you echo the value of $sql?

Comment: @ryan Thanks! Here is the new question with a new problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10670117/why-does-this-query-only-show-one-result

Answer (score 3):

```
$sql = "SELECT name, id_code from codes WHERE (id_code = '$q') OR (name='$q')";
$sql = "SELECT name, id_code from codes WHERE (id_code = '$q' OR name='$q')";
$sql = "SELECT name, id_code from codes WHERE id_code = '$q' OR name='$q'";
```

All of these will produce the same result.

Answer (score 1):

This code is correct. The reason why it doesn't work is because the needle hasn't been found in the haystack.

Answer (score 0):

This may be because the `id_code` column its a numeric column, or the values of the column are zero padded or the variables aren't been passed to the query.

Check the variables to see if they are being passed by echoing the query and take a look at the data type of the fields.

If a field is numeric, it can be assigned or compared without the quotes.

Also, if you want to search part of the `name` column, you will have to change the `=` operator to a `like` operator:

```
$sql = "SELECT name, id_code from codes WHERE (id_code = '$q') OR (name like '%$q%')";
```

The `%` means anything (zero or more chars), so the query will look for any name starting with anything, then your search therm and then ending with anything.