# Why does this query only show one result?

Tags: php, search

The query below will be used a search script.  For some reason it won't return all results where either condition is true.  What am i doing wrong?

```
$sql = "SELECT name, id_code from codes WHERE name LIKE '%$q%' OR id_code 
LIKE '%$q%'";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$query = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());

$num_rows1 = mysql_num_rows($result);

if ($result == "")
{
echo "";
}
echo "";


$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

if($rows == 0)
{
print("<div id=norequests>No results for <strong>$q</strong></div>");

}
elseif($rows > 0)
{
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{

$name = htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
$code = htmlspecialchars($row['id_code']);

}

print("$code: $name<br /> <br />");
}

}


else{
    echo '<div id="error">No results for $q.</div>';
}
```

Comment: Please use PDO instead of the dangerous mysql_ functions.

Comment: Hey, new to PHP.  Any place you recommend to get info on how to use PDO queries?

Comment: Escaped queries are very safe...

Comment: Sure. http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/ and http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers

Comment: The queries are safe, but, that's not the point. There's no error checking and all kinds of other problems with the PHP mysql_ functions.

Comment: "Won't return" - does that mean the query is returning less rows than exist in the database or does it mean the code below the query won't show the returned rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are printing outside of `while`. Which means, no matter how many results you have, only the one will be printed.

Either print inside the loop

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $name = htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
    $code = htmlspecialchars($row['id_code']);
    print("$code: $name<br /> <br />");
}
```

or collect the variables in an array while looping and use them after the loop as you like

```
$result_array = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    $name = htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
    $code = htmlspecialchars($row['id_code']);

    $result_array[] = array(
        'name' => $name,
        'code' => $code
    );
}
print_r($result_array);
```

Answer (score 3):

Your loop overwrites the value of `$name` and `$code` with each loop, so all you will eventually see is the value of the last cycle.

```
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $query ) ) {
  $name = htmlspecialchars($row['name']);
  $code = htmlspecialchars($row['id_code']);
}
```

You can either `echo` those values from within your loop, or push them onto a collection someplace:

```
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $query ) ) {
  $names[] = htmlspecialchars( $row["name"] );
  $codes[] = htmlspecialchars( $row["id_code"] );
}
```

Or you could put both values into a single array:

```
$set = array();
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $query ) ) {
  $set[] = array( 
    "Name" => htmlspecialchars( $row["name"] ),
    "Code" => htmlspecialchars( $row["id_code"] )
  );
}
```

At this point, you have loaded all of the names and codes into arrays (or *an* array) that can be manipulated after your loop has run its course.

```
print_r( $names ); // or $set
```

#### Redundant Actions

Additionally, you have some redundant code:

```
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$query  = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error: ".mysql_error());
```

This runs your query twice - no need for that.

```
$num_rows1 = mysql_num_rows($result);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($result);
```

This is counting the number of rows returned, twice. Again, no need for that.

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't be using MySQL for fulltext search (see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_text_search). Instead, consider using MySQL's fulltext capabilities: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html. Or possibly even better, use a "real" fulltext search engine like Lucene (see: http://lucene.apache.org/) or Sphinx (see: http://sphinxsearch.com/).